# Intento desplegar una aplicación NestJS y nunca inicia

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Estoy aprendiendo NestJS, intentando ejecutar una aplicación sencilla con el comando básico **"npm run start:dev"** se queda esperando y nunca arranca el servidor, así queda por todo el tiempo que lo deje, no pasa de ahí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí debería salir algo como "[NestFactory] Starting Nest application..." y después cargar todas las instancias , pero nunca pasa, ya actualicé todas las dependencias npm y no sé qué más hacer.

NOTA: ya intenté con otras aplicaciones de NestJS y ejecutan normal, el problema solo es en esta.

Adjunto package.json por si se ve algo raro

```js
{
  "name": "edman",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.4.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "helmet": "^4.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya resolví el error, no estaba ejecutando el boostrap(); MEA CULPA.

Comment: Hola Jaiver Castrillón. Me alegro que encontraras una respuesta a tu problema. Deberías añadir algo más de información, ¿cuándo o cómo se ejecuta el comnado `boostrap()`? ¿dónde iría en el código? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).